# How to auto-close PyQt/PySide window using thread?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, pyqt5, pyside2

How can I make a PyQt5 window automatically close after 30 seconds and still keep the window respond to interaction?

I'm creating a thread which sleeps for 30 seconds, and then it calls the `close()` function of the window. Right now, the code hangs at `self.close()`:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\.conda\envs\pysidedev_py27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\.conda\envs\pysidedev_py27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\Desktop\timer.py", line 47, in <lambda>
    my_win.execute_function_threaded(func=lambda: my_win.auto_close(n=3))
  File "C:\Users\fredrik\Desktop\timer.py", line 36, in auto_close
    self.close()  # hangs
RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (MyWindow) already deleted.
```

I also tried moving the threading out of the window object but then I'm still experiencing a hang on `window.close()`.

What am I doing wrong?

The code must work with Python 2.7 and 3.5.

```
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread

try:
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
except ImportError:
    try:
        from PySide2 import QtWidgets
    except ImportError:
        try:
            from PyQt4 import QtGui as QtWidgets
        except ImportError:
            try:
                from PySide import QtGui as QtWidgets
            except ImportError:
                print('giving up!')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """Auto-closing window"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Delete object when closed"""
        self.deleteLater()

    def auto_close(self, n):
        """Close self in n seconds"""
        print('going to sleep')
        for i in range(n):
            print('sleeping...')
            time.sleep(1)
        print('done sleeping!')
        self.close()  # hangs

    def execute_function_threaded(self, func):
        """Run given function in thread"""
        self.t = Thread(target=func)
        self.t.start()
        print('thread started')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
my_win = MyWindow()
my_win.show()
my_win.execute_function_threaded(func=lambda: my_win.auto_close(n=3))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please note that the Qt binding imports are just done like that in order to make this code run easier on your end ;)

Comment: I have tested the code and it does not block the widget, you could comment that SO you have, the version of PyQt, the version of Python

Comment: @eyllanesc Not sure what you mean, the window crashes here on my end regardless of Python version or Qt binding/version that I'm testing with. For example I tried Python 2.7/PySide, Python 3.5/PyQt5 where the window crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code instead of `my_win.execute_function_threaded` call:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """Auto-closing window"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(30000, self.close)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the original code doesn't work is because you are forbidden to call Qt GUI methods from secondary threads (Qt methods are not thread safe). There are several solutions to this, such as:

- using a `QTimer` (since `QTimer` doesn't use threads, and just queues up a future event in the Qt event loop that exists in the main thread, this solution should solve the segfaults - see the answer by [@ingvar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44356684/1994235))
- using a `QThread` and a custom Qt signal. Qt signals are thread safe, so you can connect a signal in a secondary thread to the `close` slot in the primary thread. Then you can emit the signal from within the secondary thread after 30 seconds to trigger the close.

The approach you should take depends on your end goal (and how much of a 'toy' example this is), but for now I see no reason to have a secondary thread. You should just go with @ingvar's answer :)

P.S. Either way, using python threads with Qt is a bad idea. Stick to `QThread` unless the thread is completely independent of the GUI.

Comment: anyone stumbling on this from the future... this comment is fine, but the last p.s. about not using python threads is dubious. You can use python threads just fine, you just have to make sure they don't affect the UI directly, but instead are connected by signals. Also make sure the thread is able to stop, otherwise it causes the GUI to hang.